# Docker Logs Issue : Logs are not created or displayed in Tomcat's logs folder in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container, war

We are using Docker container and created a Dockerfile. Inside this container we deployed war file using tomcat image 
and we can see tomcat logs at console but console logs is not updating 
after sending a request to tomcat via URL.
Also we can not see any log file inside tomcat logs folder

Can anyone help me out that how we can see tomcat logs like localhost.logs/catalina.logs/manager.logs etc

MY Dockerfile is :-

```
FROM openjdk:6-jre

ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH

COPY tomcat $CATALINA_HOME

ADD  newui.war  $CATALINA_HOME/webapps

CMD $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh && tail -F $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out

EXPOSE 8080
```

Used below script to build

```
$ docker build -t tomcat .
```

and below used to run tomcat

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 tomcat
```

Comment: Why not use the tomcat official image as base instead of java?

Comment: try checking logs inside your docker container.

Comment: did the same but it did't resolve the issue and we required only java 6 version thats why need to write java over there

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few things wrong with your dockerfile:
You mention that you need java 6, and yet the line `FROM java` as of this writing is set to use java:8.

You need to replace the FROM line with `FROM java:6-jre` or as suggested by the [official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/): `FROM openjdk:6-jre` if in 2018 you still need java 6, which is dangerous. I would also strongly suggest to use at least `FROM tomcat:7` which should be able to run java 6 applets but will include some bug fixes including support for longer Diffie-Hellman primes for HTTPS (if you are serious about your app's security).

`Copt tomcat $CATALINA_HOME` you either miss-typed the line to SO, or your image should not build at all. It should be `COPY tomcat $CATALINA_HOME`

Given that you are using the `COPY` command there is no need to use `RUN mkdir -p` prior to this, since the `COPY` command will automatically create all the required folders.

```
CMD $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh && tail -f $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out
```

First the `tail -f` part: since you are looking to tail a log file which might be created and recreated during the server's operation instead of following the FD you should be following the path by doing `tail -F` (capital F)

`startup.sh && tail` - tail will never start until startup.sh exits. A better approach is to do `tail -F $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out &` inside your startup.sh right before you start your tomcat server. That way tail will be running in the background.

Regardless this is a somewhat dangerous approach and you risk zombie processes because bash does not manage its children processes and neither does docker. I would recommend to use supervisord or something similar.

(From https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/)

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY my_first_process my_first_process
COPY my_second_process my_second_process
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

**Note:** this dockerfile sample omits a few of the best practices, e.g. removing the apt cache in the same run command as doing the apt-get update.

Personal favorite is the phusion/baseimage, but it is harder to setup since you'll need to install everything including the java into the image.

---

If with all of these modifications you still have no luck in seeing the console update, then you'll need to also post the contents of your startup.sh file or other tomcat related configurations.

**P.S.:** it might be a good idea to do `RUN mkdir -p $CATALINA_HOME/logs` just to make sure that the logs folder exists for tomcat to write to.

**P.P.S.:** the java base image is actually using openjdk instead of the oracle one. Just thought I'd point it out

Comment: did the same but logs not created in the tomcat's logs folder

Answer (score 0):

You should check tomcat logging settings. The default logging.properties in the JRE specifies a ConsoleHandler that routes logging to System.err. The default conf/logging.properties in Apache Tomcat also adds several FileHandlers that write to files.

Example logging.properties file to be placed in $CATALINA_BASE/conf:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \
           java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = 16384

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = \
   2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = \
   3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE
```

Example logging.properties for the servlet-examples web application to be placed in WEB-INF/classes inside the web application:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = servlet-examples.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

More info at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

we can not see the logs in Docker container until unless we mount it.

To build the Dockerfile:-

```
docker build -t tomcat
```

To run the Dockerfile   Image:-

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 tomcat
```

To copy the logs of tomcat present in docker container to mounted container  :-

Run this cmd to mount the container:

```
                                                1stpath    :      2ndpath
docker run \\-d \\-p 8085:8085 \\-v  /usr/local/tomcat/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs  \tomcat
```

or simply

```
docker run \\-d \\-v  /usr/local/tomcat/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs  \tomcat
```

> 1st:-/usr/local/tomcat/logs: path of root dir: where we want to copy
>   the logs  or destination
>
> 2nd:- /usr/local/tomcat/logs: path of tomcat/logs folder present in
>   docker container

tomcat:-name of image

need to change the port if it is busy

now the container is get mount

to get the list of container run : `docker ps -a`

now get the container id of latest created container:

```
docker exec -it < mycontainer > bash
```

then we can see the logs by

```
    cd /usr/local/tomcat/logs

    usr/local/tomcat/logs# less  Log Name Here
```

this to Copy any folder in docker container on root:-

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```